# PostgreSQL: create unique constraint on join table (multi-table constaint)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Imagine I have for example this SQL:

```
SELECT
    directed_events.id as event_id,
    directed_events.event_type as event_type,
    issuers.referable_id as issuer_id,
    issuers.referable_type as issuer_type,
    targets.referable_id as target_id,
    targets.referable_type as target_type
FROM
    events AS directed_events
INNER JOIN "event_refs" "issuers" 
  ON "directed_events"."id" = "issuers"."event_id"
  AND "issuers"."connection_type" = 'issuer'
INNER JOIN "event_refs" "targets" 
  ON "directed_events"."id" = "targets"."event_id"
  AND "targets"."connection_type" = 'target'
```

I want to ensure that for set of values (event_type, issuer_id, target_id) database contents is unique, so duplicate insert must be rejected.

Of course, I can do it at application level. But database level constraint is more solid approach.

Comment: It seems odd to me that if you need such a constraint, you don't have a table with all three columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, From business logic perspective, such duplicates doesn't make sense. I want results of join query to be unique in this scope

Answer (score 0):

you can use concat + distinct on

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (conc_id) *
FROM (
    SELECT
        directed_events.id as event_id,
        directed_events.event_type as event_type,
        issuers.referable_id as issuer_id,
        issuers.referable_type as issuer_type,
        targets.referable_id as target_id,
        targets.referable_type as target_type,

        -- concat columns to have only one column for unique check
        CONCAT(directed_events.event_type::text, '-', issuers.referable_id::text, '-', targets.referable_id::text) as conc_id
    FROM
        events AS directed_events
    INNER JOIN "event_refs" "issuers" 
    ON "directed_events"."id" = "issuers"."event_id"
    AND "issuers"."connection_type" = 'issuer'
    INNER JOIN "event_refs" "targets" 
    ON "directed_events"."id" = "targets"."event_id"
    AND "targets"."connection_type" = 'target'
) as data

ORDER BY conc_id ASC
```